# Fat Model, Skinny Controller in Rails with example

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller

I really want to start learning Rails best practices, especially following the "fat model, skinny controller" logic.

Say I have the following comment controller

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController

    def create
        @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
        @comment = @post.comments.create(comment_params)
        @comment.user_id = current_user.id if current_user
        @comment.save!

        if @comment.save
            redirect_to post_path(@post)
        else
            render 'new'
        end
    end

    def edit
        @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
        @comment = @post.comments.find(params[:id])
    end

    def update
        @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
        @comment = @post.comments.find(params[:id])

        if @comment.update(params[:comment].permit(:comment))
            redirect_to post_path(@post)
        else
            render 'Edit'
        end
    end

    def destroy
        @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
        @comment = @post.comments.find(params[:id])
        @comment.destroy
        redirect_to post_path(@post)
    end

    private

    def comment_params
        params.require(:comment).permit(:comment)
    end
```

What's a good place to start refactoring the code? 
Immediately I think I an make the **@post** and **@comment** in both **edit** and **update** into a separate method, follow by calling a **before_action** on the method. But that is still putting all the code in the controller.

Are there any code that I can move to the model? If so, how should I structure them?

Comment: You should try to search for relevant articles on the fat model approach -- it's not something that can (or should) be covered in a couple of paragraphs on SO. Speaking very generally, "fat model" means that you put your business logic in the model -- it does not mean that you put *all* logic in the model. The only part of your code that is begging to be refactored is the fact that you call @comment.save! (a forced save) followed by if @comment.save (which is a second attempt to save the same comment you already saved. You're begging to fail any unique validations.

Comment: @MarsAtomic actually a double save won't create a duplicate record, but yea it's an extra unneeded save.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code doesn't have much room for improvement, it's a basic crud, here's an example of a before_action like you suggested

```
before_action :load_post_and_comment, only: %i(edit update destroy)

def load_post_and_comment
  @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
  @comment = @post.comments.find(params[:id])
end
```

And here a couple of other notes

```
def create
  # ...
  @comment.save!
  if @comment.save
    # ...
  else
    # ..
  end
end
```

In this codition the you should remove the extra `@comment.save!` you only need to save once.

```
def update
  # ...
  if @comment.update(params[:comment].permit(:comment))
    # ...
  else
    # ...
  end
end
```

You already have the `comment_params` method, use it, because if you at any point add a new attribute to the comment, you'll update that method but you'll probably forget this part and you'll get werid errors till you notice that you need to permit here too.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to *really* go all out with the skinny controller model, there is this gem: https://github.com/NullVoxPopuli/skinny_controllers

Where, you'd configure your `CommentsController` like so:

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController
  include SkinnyControllers::Diet

  def create
    if model.errors.present?
      render 'new'
    else
      redirect_to post_path(model)
    end
  end

  def update
    redirect_to post_path(model)
  end

  # ... etc

  private

  def comment_params
    params.require(:comment).permit(:comment)
  end

end
```